# C++ | Определить координаты Mouse в SFML

Tags: c++, sfml, position, мышь

Не могу догнать, как правильно определить координаты курсора?

Например, с помощью документации SFML я пришел к выводу, что брать координаты мыши нужно так:

```
sf::Mouse::getPosition(WindowBase(VideoMode));
```

Затем, я пробую записать эти координаты так:

```
 Vector2f position = Mouse::getPosition();
```

Ну и пытаюсь сравнением и if нарисовать что-то, когда курсор мыши находится по этим координатам...

```
 if (position == Vector2f(110, 110)) {
        rect3.setPosition(Vector2f(110, 110));
        window.draw(rect3);
    }
```

Я понял, что я вообще неправильно что-то делаю, так?

Как мне нарисовать rect3

```
rect3.setPosition(Vector2f(110, 110));
        window.draw(rect3);
```

В случае, если курсор мыши находится в диапазоне координат
от `Vector2f(110, 110)` до `Vector2f(210, 210);`
То есть, получается квадрат...

В общем, не получается мне понять логику как это делать.
Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам нашел ответ.

Сначала нужно определить переменную типа `Vector2i` (смотреть документацию по Vector2).

```
sf::Vector2i mousePos;
```

Затем, в цикле `isOpen`, присвоить координаты мыши ранее созданной переменной `mousePos`;

```
mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
```

Далее, уже используем по нужде полученные координаты:

- `mousePos.x` - координаты по x.
- `mousePos.y` - координаты по y.

Comment: Вы также можете получать эти данные при помощи `sf::Event`, для этого в цикле обработки событий окна вы должны сделать проверку на тип события `event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved`, а затем  забрать координаты в `event.mouseMove`. Главным преимуществом данного способа является пониженная нагрузка на процессор, более того, событие будет срабатывать только при движении мыши в пределах окна. Ещё, вы можете напрямую установить callback функцию GLFW с обработкой всех событий мыши и клавиатуры без SFML. Это может быть полезно для повышения частоты опроса, точнее обработки.